# Trying to change policies at runtime : IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: kid

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to have the user decide wether to use the standard login or with TOTP.

My Setup:

```
<add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_signupsignin_1" /> 
 <add key="ida:EditProfilePolicyId" value="B2C_1_profileediting1" />
 <add key="ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="B2C_1_passwordreset1" />
```

In the code do following:

```
public void SignUpSignInTOTP(string redirectUrl)
{
    redirectUrl = redirectUrl ?? "/";
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Globals.TOTPPasswordPolicyId);

    // Use the default policy to process the sign up / sign in flow
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl });
    return;
}
```

where as

```
public static string TOTPPasswordPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TOTPPasswordPolicyId"];
```

If I set the the TOTPPasswordPolicyId in the ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId it works fine. But if I change it at runtime I get the error.

IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: kid

I do not understand why this is happening? Any sugestions?

The B2C_1_signupsignin_1 is a user flow and the B2C_1A_TOTP_signup_signin is a custom policy. 
Can this maybe be the problem. Is it not possible to mix these?

regards
Stefan

Comment: Is this a combination of User Flows and Custom Policies?

Comment: Yes it is a combination. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Possibly, at runtime the OWIN pipeline will initialise the metadata endpoint. It is based on the policyId, and custom policies use a different signing key compared to user flows. So the KID will not match. So make sure in startup.auth.cs that the runtime change of policy id is also being accounted for in the metadata url generation.